# Jquery check element exists by data attribute matching only the start of a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I want to be able to check to see if a specific data attribute exists that starts with a specific value.

for example lets say i have the following HTML code:

```
 <div data-attr="123ABC"></div>
 <div data-attr="123456"><div>
 <div data-attr="TEST"></div>
```

and then i want to find any use of the data tag of `data-attr` that starts with `123`

```
 if ($('[data-attr="123"]').length > 0) { 
     //do something
 }
```

This appears to always return `0` as i have no `data-attr="123"` How would i make it so i can check for only that specific data attribute that starts with 123 and has anything after that?

Comment: [Here's a search of the API documentation for "attribute starts with"](http://api.jquery.com/?s=attribute+starts+with).

Comment: You might be able to do that checking if the indexOf "123" of said attribute 0 (which means the string starts with that value). EDIT: They posted a nice solution alredy so..nevermind ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is how

```
if ($('[data-attr^="123"]').length > 0) { 
 //do something
}
```